# Slow motion camera feature on iPod?

Tags: video, ipod, camera, hardware-recommendation

I am thinking of obtaining an iPod (any generation) for recording slow-motion videos, like the ones that can be shot on an iPhone 5s and above.

Is there an iPod that can do slo-mo, or is an iPhone the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [iPod touch 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Touch_(6th_generation)#Hardware) has a camera equivalent to that in the iPhone 6.

As such it is the first (and as of August 2017, the only) iPod that can record slo-mo video, at 120 frames per second in 720p resolution.

> The iPod touch features an 8MP rear iSight camera with video which can record in 1080p at 30fps, or **120fps in slow-motion mode that records at 720p**.

Comment: Thanks, and do you know about iPod 5? It makes sense, judging by your suggestion that it has same slo mo feature as iPhone 5s?

Comment: Unfortunately the iPod touch 5 is the equivalent of an iPhone 5, and therefore does not support slo-mo video.